# Xcode 'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:' error?

Tags: xcode

```
Error: " Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "f(int, int, int const (*) [8], int const (*) [8], int*, int*)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o "
      ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
      clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried running the exact same code on Visual Studio 2010, and it worked! Any idea why it doesn't work here? My Mac is 64bit. Thanks!

Here's the code on the files that's giving the error:

```
#include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  int p,q;

  int f( int,  int,const int [][8],const int [][8], int [],int []);
```

Comment: Did you define the function `f()`?

Comment: That is a declaration, but no definition. Did you define it?

Comment: Usually by providing implemenation code. If you have a library with this function, you can link it in your program. However, I do not know any library that includes a function called `f()`, but maybe there is one in VS 2010.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for your help. Is it possible to show me the code you would implement to define ' f '? Thank you! Also, would you define it on the .h file or the main .cpp file?

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you haven't provided an implementation of your f(..) function.

In your main.cpp file, simply implement the function, like:

```
int f( int,  int,const int [][8],const int [][8], int [],int [])
{
    // Do stuff... 
}
```